# Can I set unknown number of object args in console.WriteLine?

Tags: c#

i like to have a general function that wraps the Console.WriteLine function

For example :

```
logFunc("foo {0} bar {1}" ,"1","w")
logFunc("foo {0} bar {1} bar {2}","1","w",2)
logFunc("foo {0} bar {1} bar {2} bar {3}",1,2,3,4)

public logFunc(string formatStr, params object[] args) {

   console.WriteLine(formatStr,/* what should be here ?*/ .... );
}
```

how can i set console.WriteLine to get N number of arguments ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Console.WriteLine`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.console.writeline?view=net-5.0#System_Console_WriteLine_System_String_System_Object___) itself has an overload that takes the format string and an array of objects. So you can simply pass the `args` array:

```
Console.WriteLine(formatStr, args);
```